# Flutter scrollable positioned list support rtl direction?

Tags: flutter

I use the [scrollable positioned package](https://pub.dev/packages/scrollable_positioned_list) in the following code to move between elements via the index, and it works fine in the case of LTR, but when converting to RTL, some problems occur and the transition is not correct!! I tried to find out the problem but couldn't.

How can this be solved?

**LTR:**

[image]

**RTL:**

[image]

The code:

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  int currentIndex = 0;
  TextDirection textDirection = TextDirection.ltr;

  late final ItemScrollController itemScrollController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    itemScrollController = ItemScrollController();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Directionality(
      textDirection: textDirection,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Scrollable positioned list')),
        body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 100,
              child: ScrollablePositionedList.separated(
                itemCount: 10,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemScrollController: itemScrollController,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
                separatorBuilder: (context, index) => const SizedBox(width: 10),
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
                  width: 100,
                  height: 50,
                  alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    border: currentIndex == index ? Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 4) : null,
                  ),
                  child:
                      Text(index.toString(), style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.w800)),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 40),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  if (textDirection == TextDirection.ltr) {
                    textDirection = TextDirection.rtl;
                  } else {
                    textDirection = TextDirection.ltr;
                  }
                });
              },
              child: Text(textDirection.toString()),
            )
          ],
        ),
        floatingActionButton: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: [
            FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  if (currentIndex != 0) {
                    currentIndex--;
                    itemScrollController.scrollTo(index: currentIndex, duration: const Duration(microseconds: 500), alignment: 0.10);
                  }
                });
              },
              child: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
            ),
            FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  if (currentIndex < 9) {
                    currentIndex++;
                    itemScrollController.scrollTo(index: currentIndex, duration: const Duration(microseconds: 500), alignment: 0.10);
                  }
                });
              },
              child: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this might be a bug either from [scrollable positioned package](https://pub.dev/packages/scrollable_positioned_list) library or in `Directionality` Widget. A simple workaround would be reversing the `List` Widget by toggling the reverse parameter according to direction.

Reverse property of `List` Widget only displays the data in reverse order but the functioning remains the same hence you need to change the button functionality accordingly.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:scrollable_positioned_list/scrollable_positioned_list.dart';

void main() => runApp(
      const MyApp(), // Wrap your app
    );

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  int currentIndex = 0;
  TextDirection textDirection = TextDirection.ltr;

  late final ItemScrollController itemScrollController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    itemScrollController = ItemScrollController();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 100,
              child: ScrollablePositionedList.separated(
                reverse: textDirection == TextDirection.ltr ? false : true, // reverse the list
                itemCount: 10,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemScrollController: itemScrollController,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
                separatorBuilder: (context, index) => const SizedBox(width: 10),
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
                  width: 100,
                  height: 50,
                  alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    border: currentIndex == index
                        ? Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 4)
                        : null,
                  ),
                  child: Text(index.toString(),
                      style: const TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.w800)),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 40),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  if (textDirection == TextDirection.ltr) {
                    textDirection = TextDirection.rtl;
                  } else {
                    textDirection = TextDirection.ltr;
                  }
                });
              },
              child: Text(textDirection.toString()),
            )
          ],
        ),
        floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
        floatingActionButton: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: [
            FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  if (textDirection == TextDirection.ltr) {
                    if (currentIndex != 0) {
                      currentIndex--;
                      itemScrollController.scrollTo(
                          index: currentIndex,
                          duration: const Duration(microseconds: 500),
                          alignment: 0.10);
                    }
                  } else {
                    if (currentIndex < 9) {
                      currentIndex++;
                      itemScrollController.scrollTo(
                          index: currentIndex,
                          duration: const Duration(microseconds: 500),
                          alignment: 0.10);
                    }
                  }
                });
              },
              child: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
            ),
            FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  if (textDirection == TextDirection.ltr) {
                    if (currentIndex < 9) {
                      currentIndex++;
                      itemScrollController.scrollTo(
                          index: currentIndex,
                          duration: const Duration(microseconds: 500),
                          alignment: 0.10);
                    }
                  } else {
                    if (currentIndex != 0) {
                      currentIndex--;
                      itemScrollController.scrollTo(
                          index: currentIndex,
                          duration: const Duration(microseconds: 500),
                          alignment: 0.10);
                    }
                  }
                });
              },
              child: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Jus to simplify the solution of @Ramji, here is how the workaround works:

```
bool isRTL = true; // <- Arabic: true, English: false

return Directionality(
  textDirection: TextDirection.ltr, // <- Always should be 'ltr'
  child: ScrollablePositionedList.separated(
    reverse: isRTL ? true : false,
    // ...
  ),
);
```

Just declare `isRTL` properly to detect the current language whether it is `Right-To-Left: true` or `Left-To-Right: false`.